# Guava Table to CSVPrinter with header

Tags: java, csv, guava

This question is an extension to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38524942/7699037).
The OP asked to print a Guava Table with help of a `CSVPrinter`:

```
final Table<String, String, Double> graph = HashBasedTable.create();

graph.put("A", "FirstCol", 0.0);
graph.put("A", "SecondCol", 1.0);
graph.put("B", "FirstCol", 0.1);
graph.put("B", "SecondCol", 1.1);

final Appendable out = new StringBuilder();
try {
    final CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.print(out);

    printer.printRecords(graph.rowMap().entrySet()
      .stream()
      .map(entry -> ImmutableList.builder()
            .add(entry.getKey())
            .addAll(entry.getValue().values())
            .build())
      .collect(Collectors.toList()));

} catch (final IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(out);
```

With the previous code which integrates the accepted answer, the `CSVPrinter` prints the following table:

```
A,0.0,1.0
B,0.1,1.1
```

I want to know if there is a method to store the strings in the table column keys as a header for the CSV, so in the example it should print the following:

```
AorB,FirstCol,SecondCol
A,0.0,1.0
B,0.1,1.1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section [Printing with headers](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html#Printing_with_headers) of Apache Commons CSV User Guide suggests using 
[CSVFormat.withHeader](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withHeader-java.lang.String...-). In your case it could look like:

```
final String[] header = new ImmutableList.Builder<String>()
    .add("AorB").addAll(graph.columnKeySet())
    .build().toArray(new String[0]);
final CSVPrinter printer = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(header).print(out);
```